# h2 h4 title graphics need drop shadow over image

Tags: css

I'm using a transparent png file for the background for my `h2` and `h4` elements it has a shadow at the bottom which I'd like to appear over the featured images like you can see here: https://redpen.io/epqvnw

Right now on the site http://www.mediray.co.nz/preview the `h2` background is cropped. I've worked with inspect element exhaustively. At some point I could get it on top but it lowered the opacity of every other element on the page. I am using `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);` for my site-inner I guess they're must be a conflict.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. If I wasn't clear enough or you need further information please let me know.

Comment: Thank you gearsdigital that is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative` and `z-index: 1` in `dynamik.css` at line `1457`

```
#ez-home-container-wrap .ez-widget-area h4,
#ez-home-slider-container-wrap .ez-widget-area h4 {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #DDDDDD;
    color: #838383;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest simply using an invert box-shadow on the image, creating the illusion of a shadow being cast by the heading. Like so:

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 5px -5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jtFb8/

Or if you don't want to use CSS3 then put the shadow on the top of the image rather than the background of the header.